# Turn off remote Oracle database with bash through ssh

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I'm trying to write a start|stop script to stop my databases on different linux servers remotely.
I have a server with root and ssh keys to all destination servers.
Generally I need to:
run a scripts as root, ssh to another server, su - oracle, run sqlplus and shutdown the db.

That's what i have for now to stop the db.
remote server:

```
stop(){
A=`ssh root@10.10.10.110 ps -ef | grep smon_D | wc -l`
echo $A

if [[ $A -gt 0 ]]
then
        echo "Found SMON process is alive, stopping the DB"
        ssh root@10.10.10.110 su - oradaily -c "/oracle_general/start_stop/stop_db.sh"
else
        echo "Found SMON process is down, DB has already been stopped"
fi
}
```

The same server as the 1st script:

```
cat /oracle_general/start_stop/stop_db.sh
sudo su - oradaily -c /oracle_general/start_stop/stop_DB.sh
```

Server with the db:

```
cat /oracle_general/start_stop/stop_DB.sh
sqlplus -prelim "/as sysdba" <<EOF
shutdown immediate;
exit
EOF
```

I've tried this different ways and was getting different errors. Please advise.

Comment: Please pick a particular script that you're running and [edit] your question to describe in detail what happens when you run it. Include the exact text of the errors that you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Well I just had to call the stop scripts in the 1st one.
1st script should have been run from an external node and the second one is placed locally on the node with db. A file share will help greatly.

Summary:
In the if block I call a script that is located on a remote server that stops everything. That's it.